# Quelle serait une autre façon d’énoncer « Ça va faire mal au portefeuille »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, constructions, reformulation

Exemple:

Tu as brisé le nouvel iPhone 13 de ta sœur, cela fera mal à ton portefeuille car tu devras lui en racheter un.

Dans le même esprit, je suis à la recherche d’une reformulation d’un registre plus soutenu de « mettre la main au portefeuille » , qui se rapproche en signification de l’autre phrase en titre.

Comment: Est-que c'est le mot portefeuille qui vous gêne? Alors, pourquoi pas:  Je suis obligé de **débourser** le prix d'un nouveau portable.

Comment: J’adopte ce verbe!

Comment: @Lambie Soit dit au passage, pourquoi ne pas faire de votre commentaire une réponse? Non seulement je lui donnerais un vote positif, mais je l’approuverais aussi comme étant la réponse la plus pertinente.

Comment: Je pense que je trouve plus usuel d'avoir un truc qui fait _un trou dans mes finances_ ou _dans mon compte de banque_ que ces références au portefeuille. _Ça va te coûter cher_, aussi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tu as détruit le nouvel iPhone 13 de ta sœur. Tes finances vont en pâtir car son remplaçant sera à ta charge.

Comment: Pas pire du tout! Pour ne pas dire excellent!

Answer (score 0):

« mettre la main au portefeuille » :
Une de mes tantes disait :
"Il va falloir sortir les billets !"

Answer (score -1):

Dans le même registre (très ordinaire, familier, ou plus familier)  on peut utiliser « coûter bonbon ». La note sur l'origine de cette expression donne une expression de plus, mais qui est franchement vulgaire : « coûter la peau des fesses ».

- Tu as brisé le nouvel Iphone 13 de ta soeur, ça va te couter bonbon, car tu devras lui en racheter un.

> ([Internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/1062/couter-bonbon/))  **coûter bonbon**
> Signification
> Coûter très cher.
> Origine
> L'origine de l'expression "coûter bonbon" n'est pas très claire. Le mot "bonbon" semble davantage un redoublement du mot "bon", répétition qui met l'emphase sur le prix, qui est très important (coûter bon étant assimilé à coûter cher). Une origine plus graveleuse de l'expression, assimilant le "bonbon" à une partie intime, est également possible ; on peut alors assimiler l'expression à "coûter la peau des fesses".

Pour une expression similaire à « mettre la main au portefeuille », il y a « payer l'addition » ; c'est aussi d'un registre familier.

> ([Internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/4791/payer-l-addition/))   **Payer l'addition**
> Signification
> Régler la facture, payer la note.
> Origine
> Cette expression est née au cours du XXe siècle et s'utilise dans le langage courant pour exprimer le fait de régler la facture d'un restaurant, un café, etc. Elle peut aussi signifier qu'il faut payer pour les conséquences de ces actes

Si un registre plus soutenu est le but, alors les termes mêmes de la définition précédente sont parfaits.

- *régler la facture*, *payer la note*

S'il n'est pas question de facture ou de note, on peut aussi dire tout simplement « payer » (*langue courante*).

- Elle n'a pas fait d'ennui, elle a payé. (*user LPH*)

Comment: **"je suis à la recherche d’une reformulation d’un registre plus soutenu"**

Comment: @Lambie C'est ce « dans le même esprit » qui m'a induit en erreur.